# Django / MYSQL foreign key best practice

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, django-orm

I have three models:

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Phone(models.Model):
    calls = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    agent_phone_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Chat(models.Model):
    chats = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    agent_chat_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Chat and Phone links to agent with foreign key. 
I want to make a table like this:

```
agent1 | sum(calls) | sum(chats)
agent2 | sum(calls) | sum(chats)
agent3 | sum(calls) | sum(chats)
```

First question is: 
I've read about SQL foreign key as a way to maintain data and referential integrity. However in my case, there are miss call and chat (agent didn't pick it up) that generate rows of data has empty value on agent_name. So when I'm inserting the phone/chat data and update the FK, I have leave the FK empty and kinda that conflicts with the idea of FK. What's the best way to handle this?

Second question is: is using Foreign key the only way to perform SQL join table  query in Django ORM? Is there any other way around it?

Thank you !

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nullable foreign keys but if it bothers you, you can insert an agent named 'Missed Calls' and use it instead of setting the FK to null.